# C# Change SelectedIndex after adding new item to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox which gets the elements automatically from a ObservableCollection. If the user adds an element with a button click to the collection. an item is added with its name to the combobox (data binding). How can I implement that the selected index goes automatically to the new item from the collection?

Comment: Please add some code to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the "SelectedIndex" property of your combobox, and when you add an item, you just update this value like this :

```
ObservableCollection<Item> list = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

IndexC = list.Count() - 1;
```

and you bind on IndexC.

Answer (score 1):

Expose a `SelectedItem` property in your ViewModel along with the `ObservableCollection`, then bind `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to it.

You can then set `SelectedItem` to the newly added item in your ViewModel at the same time it's added.

You don't mention whether you are using MVVM or codebehind, but basically it would be something like:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection}, SelectedItem={Binding MySelectedItem} />
```

Code for button click (in view model)

```
var element = new MyElement();
MyCollection.Add(element);
MySelectedItem = element;
```

This will only work if you are using a view model with `INotifyPropertyChanged` since the combo needs to know when MySelectedItem gets changed.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: comboBox.SelectedItem = list? I don't get your proposition